# Split XML on node and insert general info

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

A customer can supply a consolidated XML with the following structure:

```
<invoices>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info/>
    <address/>
    <product>
        <id>A</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>B</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>C</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>2000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info/>
    <address/>
    <product>
        <id>D</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
</invoices>
```

The root element "invoices" can contain multiple instances of "invoice" (the order itself, in this case 2 orders) 
However "invoice" can also contain multiple instances of "product" (order lines, 3 orderlines for order_id 1000 and 1 for order_id 2000)

What we need is a an XML per order line containing one "product" and "invoice" with the order_id, general info and addrress always present.

```
<invoices>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <product>
        <general_info/>
        <address/>
        <id>A</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <product>
        <general_info/>
        <address/>
        <id>B</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <product>
        <general_info/>
        <address/>
        <id>C</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>2000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info/>
    <address/>
    <product>
        <id>D</id>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </product>
</invoice>
</invoices>
```

We have been looking at a multiple split scenario like this:
1. Split on invoice to get the seperate orders
2. Split the seperate orders into orderlines and transform (XSL) the seperated XML's to include the order_id, general info and address.

Split 1 (on "invoice") is achieved without issues (albeit with the help of an external program).

What we can't quite get to work can't quite to work is the split on  and preserve the general info.
Sofar we have tried to tranfsorm the XML using template matches and for-each statements but can't quite get it to work properly.

If someone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems straight-forwards with

```
  <xsl:template match="invoices">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
      <invoice>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../order_id"/>
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="../general-info, ../address, *"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </invoice>
  </xsl:template>
```

full sample is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="invoices">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
      <invoice>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../order_id"/>
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="../general-info, ../address, *"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </invoice>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin, that indeed works for the XML sample.
Just noticed that in the production XML that the node "product" is actually one level lower (parent node "products").

```
<invoices>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info>General A</general_info>
    <address>Adres A</address>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>A</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>B</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>C</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
    </products>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>2000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info>General B</general_info>
    <address>Adres B</address>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>D</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
    </products>
</invoice>
</invoices>
```

I have adjusted the  apply-templates to reflect this but have issues to get the latter part of the XSLT working (template match="product")

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="invoices">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice/products/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="product">
    <invoice>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../order_id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../general_info, ../address, *"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </invoice>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output contains the data of "item" but "order_id", "general_info" and "address" are missing.
I presume this is because of the level at which "product" is and this does not match with "../xxxxxx" anymore?

Comment: Please don't post changed requirements as answers, instead edit your question with the new code samples. As for the level, you of course then need to look up two levels with e.g. `../../general_info` instead of `../general_info`. Or select `ancestor::invoice/general_info`.

Comment: Sorry about that, in future posts I'll update the original question instead.
I have adjusted the XSLT accordingly and that works now.

One more question though.
In the production XML the invoice number is an entity instead of a node, ex. 
    <invoice number="20181230008601">
How can I copy this to a node "invoicenumber"?